# Average length of random path

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, approximation, random-walk

Let G be a directed graph of n vertices (indexed 0 , 1, 2, ... , n-1).

Each vertex is connected to the next vertex and the 0 vertex (in directed edge from it to the next / 0 vertex).

(the 0 vertex connects to himself and to the 1 veryex and the n-1 vertex connected only to 0 vertex).

lets say we're going with random steps (with uniform probability) on the graph until we cover all of it.

what's the average length of a path starting at 0 and ending at 0?

(when we get to the n-1 vertex we don't step anymore).

I computed that the probability of a path to get to the n-1 vertex is $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, but I cant compute the average length of a path.

I also only care about its big-O-notation value - asymptotic approximation (if its between $\frac{n}{2}$ to $\frac{n}{3}$ I care about the fact its O(n))

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction between "ending at $0$" and "when we get to the $n-1$ vertex we don't step anymore" – please clarify. In my answer I assumed that the walk stops at $n-1$.

Comment: @joriki yeah I meant a path is either starting and ending at 0 or starting at 0 and ending at n-1

Answer (score 0):

As the walk tries to get from vertex $j$ to vertex $n-1$ without returning to $0$, it has probability $2^{j-n+1}$ to succeed, so vertex $j$ is expected to be visited $2^{n-1-j}$ times. The expected length of the path is the sum of these expected visit counts minus $1$ and thus

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-1-j}-1=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j-1=2^n-2\;.
$$

Comment: but I asked to the average path length , like if I have 4 vertices and the walk:
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 
then I have 3 paths in lengths: 2, 1, 3 and for this example the average path length is 2.

Comment: @Daniel: I think I understand now what you mean. That's not at all clear from the question. Please clarify the question accordingly. Also, if the path lengths in your example are $2,1,3$, then you're not actually taking the paths ending in $0$, you're only counting the length of the path up to the last vertex before the return to $0$.

Comment: yeah you are right, I do count up just the steps from 0 to one vertex before the next zero